# Using weinre to debug an cordova iOS app

Tags: ios5, cordova-2.0.0, weinre

I'm looking for a way to debug a cordova app running on iOS. Will weinre work with an app that  is already compiled ?

Answer (score 0):

Weinre will work. Personally I do not like it that much. It keeps doing ajax call making performance poor. The idea itself is great.

Xcode 4.3 - use iWebInspector: http://www.iwebinspector.com/ - you will need to install an other chromium version though.

Or get Xcode 4.5 - it has an integrated remote debugger. Warning - you are not allowed to compile using Xcode 4.5 for the appstore.